# How to use Delphi Inc() and Dec() procedures in C++ Builder

Tags: delphi, c++builder, c++builder-xe

I'm a newbie programmer. I need to use Delphi's `Inc()` and `Dec()` procedures in C++ Builder XE like this:

```
Inc(Filler);

Dec(GridClientWidth);
```

Anyone can help me how to do this?

Comment: Some minor nitpicking: `Inc` and `Dec` are neither methods nor operators, but procedures.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, "minor nitpicking"--, as you found out, `Inc`and `Dec` are actually functions:-). [`"System.Dec"`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Dec).

Comment: @LURD That would appear to be a documentation bug.

Comment: @LU RD: Not in Delphi 2009, at least, even though the CodeInsight lies about that point...

Comment: The name of the language might give you a clue...?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, documented the same in XE2 and XE3. I can't check those right now, but TP7 and up to Delphi 2007 have them as procedures.

Comment: @LURD The documentation is simply wrong.

Comment: [`QC 112600 "System.Dec() wrongly declared as a function"`](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=112600)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for the `++` and `--` [operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec):

```
Filler++;
GridClientWidth--;
```

In C++ these operators are baked into the language. In Delphi, `Inc` and `Dec` are implemented as [intrinsic routines](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Delphi_Intrinsic_Routines).

Comment: @David: I just noticed that `Inc`/`Dec` are procedures that have return values (at least in Delphi 2009). Funny.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Are you sure? They have no return value in D6 or D2010, the two closes versions I can find to D2009.

Comment: @David: See http://privat.rejbrand.se/DelphiDec.png. However, in XE3 they appear to be [functions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Dec).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand The truth is always arbitrated by the compiler. And the compiler says no when you try to read the return value of `inc` or `dec`

Comment: @David: I just tired, and in fact you cannot use the value 'returned' by Dec in Delphi 2009. So perhaps the CodeInsight is a bit off. But has this changed in XE3?

Comment: Syntactically, `Inc` and `Dec` are procedures and you yourself have said in one of the comments that the compiler doesn't let you read their return values. Why then are you calling them *functions* in your answer?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - they are just procedures in Delphi 2009. Ignore Documentation and CodeInsight as bugs.

Comment: @AndriyM Because the terminology is somewhat overloaded. In C++ functions refers to what in Delphi we would name functions, procedures and methods. I will change the answer though to match the terminology used in the topic to which I link.